# Introduction to bump functions/ mollifiers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

I want to introduce a small perturbation into a particular point of a smooth function, and then, use bumo functions to smooth out the perturbed function. Could any of you recommend a good introduction/ examples which I could use to self tutor myself on the job at hand? I have undergraduate level introduction to real analysis and calculus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Evans, *Partial Differential equations*, page 264. I assume Folland's book should also have this as it is quite standard.